# VNC Viewer: Invalid endpoint: port not correctly specified

Tags: vnc, vino

I have enabled Screen Sharing on my Ubuntu with the default settings (Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS).
My Ubuntu tells me I have to use the address: `vnc://ZABBIX.local`

But when I try to connect with VNC Viewer I get the error `Invalid endpoint: port not correctly specified`. What do I wrong? I had used the default settings on my Ubuntu. Can a firewall cause this issue?

I had [read](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Servers) that VINO is the default vnc server and that you don't have to install something else? But how can you configure VINO?

What can I do to further diagnose this problem?

Comment: @user1070533 Thanks for your suggestion. I had also same issue on Ubuntu 20.4 version. My remote computer IP was `192.168.233.252` \
RDP through `vnc-viewer` working for me by dropping `vnc://` \
I connected correctly with `192.168.233.252:5900` \
[Here is the screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMT3F.png) **Here are some steps to enable RDP for Ubuntu** \
How to enable/configure Remote Desktop Sharing on Ubuntu: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/07/remote-desktop-sharing-ubuntu-20-04/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just had the same issue with VNC Viewer on macOS-Mojave. Surprisingly I found that dropping `vnc://` made it work,

e.g. `server:port`

not `vnc://server:port`

Comment: adding on here, I also had be sure to drop the trailing `/`